# Private access to the path within RewriteEngine rule

Tags: mod-rewrite, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I have the following .htaccess file (usual one for MediaWiki):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^wiki/(.*)$ /w/index.php?title=$1 [PT,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^wiki/*$ /w/index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/*$ /w/index.php [L,QSA]
```

And I want to restrict access to some paths (e.g. ^wiki/Private/(.*)$) with the password.

Is there any possibility to do that using .htaccess? There is no /wiki/ directory, so it isn't possible to put .htpasswd inside it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would typically do this using `<Location>` directives, but these can only be specified in your server configuration (i.e., not in `.htaccess` files).  Is there a particular reason you're trying to do this with a `.htaccess` file?

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^wiki/(.*)$ /w/index.php?title=$1 [PT,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^wiki/*$ /w/index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/*$ /w/index.php [L,QSA]

<Location /wiki/Private/>
    # put your auth configuration here
</Location>
```

Comment: Yes, it isn't my own server but web hosting.

Answer (score -1):

you could use something like:

```
<AuthnProviderAlias file yourfile-htpasswd>
        AuthUserFile    /somedir/htpasswd
</AuthnProviderAlias>
```

in a server configuration file to assign an alias for an authentication provider.
then, something like:

```
AuthBasicProvider yourfile-htpasswd
AuthName "Temporary Login"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
```

in a `.htaccess` file (in `Private`) should work.

see: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authn_alias.html

Comment: OP indicated that the filesystem does not correspond to the URL structure so there is no "Private" directory into which one would put a .htaccess file.

Comment: hm, point taken - if there is no wiki, no Private, no other real directory at all then there is no .htaccess file covering the case.

Comment: That's why the question was asked ;)
There's no real directory — only path alias which I want to make private.